# hide implementation of C# 'using's arguments

Tags: c#, using-statement

I'm trying to abstract marshaling IntPtr to and from structs (actually class, so it's reference type) of data shared with native code.

I have this helper class:

```
class NativeStruct<StructType> : IDisposable
{
    public NativeStruct()
    {
        _DataPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(StructType)));
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(_DataPtr, _Data);
    }
    public NativeStruct(IntPtr dataPtr)
    {
        _DataPtr = dataPtr;
        Marshal.PtrToStructure(_DataPtr, _Data);
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(_Data, _DataPtr, true);
    }

    public StructType Data { get { return _Data; } }

    IntPtr _DataPtr;
    public StructType _Data;
}
```

Is there anyway to make this code implicit:

```
using (Shared_s data = new Toolbox.NativeStruct<DataStruct>(myIntPtr).Data)
{
    data.someMember = someValue;
}
```

Some way to change this to

```
EditStruct(DataStruct, myIntPtr)
{
    data.someMember = someValue;
}
```

In C++ I would have used a macro like

```
#define EditStruct(StructType, IntPtr) using  \
(Shared_s data = new Toolbox.NativeStruct<StructType>(IntPtr).data)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest thing you can do here is use lambda expressions:

```
EditStruct<DataStruct>(myIntPtr, data =>
{
    data.someMember = someValue;
});
```

Definition of `EditStruct()`:

```
void EditStruct<TStruct>(IntPtr dataPtr, Action<TStruct> action) 
     where TStruct : struct
{
   using (var s = new Toolbox.NativeStruct<TStruct>(dataPtr))
   {
     action(s.Data);
   }
}
```

Comment: That looks better than the using statement however, I have no idea on how to implement.

Comment: That is the implementation. The `data => {...}` is converted into a delegate to a method, which is called as `action(data)` in `EditStruct()`.

Comment: @Xaade I "went" this route once. I have reverted in *most* cases to the vanilla using. Syntax-wise this is a nightmare for nested code IMOHO.

Comment: Oh, so the action is passed as an argument to the lambda.... ZOMG haha. Now it makes sense.

Comment: The data (`DataStruct` instance) is passed as an argument to the lambda, yes.

Comment: Well, I'm stuck on VS 2005, so I don't think I can use lambdas. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

C# 2.0 version:

```
EditStruct<DataStruct>(myIntPtr, delegate(DataStruct data)
{
    data.someMember = someValue;
});

void EditStruct<TStruct(IntPtr dataPtr, Action<StructType> action) where TStruct : struct
{
    using (Toolbox.NativeStruct<StructType> s = new Toolbox.NativeStruct<StructType>(dataPtr))
    {
        action(s.Data);
    }
}
```